# Why does [\W_]+ with i modifier in Javascript regex match i,k,s?

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox

Forgot to remove the i modifier in a pattern, that should strip out non alphanumeric characters:

```
str.replace(/[\W_]+/gi," ");
```

And wondered, that `[\W_]` will match `i`,`k` and with `+`  quantifier even `s` :D

Without the i modifier it's working fine. And of course the i modifier is a mistake, but I don't understand this weird behavior: [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/kD6lJ6/1) and [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z87y9mxr/)

I'm using Firefox 32.0.1

[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce that (FF 35, IE 8, Chromium 39)

Comment: Me neither (Safari 6.x)

Comment: As a workaround, it seems that splitting the regex into two does the right thing:`str.replace(/[\W]/gi," ").replace(/[\_]/gi," ")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug that affects Firefox 32.0 and 32.0.1.

It has already been fixed on Firefox 33 Beta.

Comment: I also suspect it might be a bug. I get the same behaviour as OP using FF 32 but it works fine in Chrome 37